# How to Display Vertical result to Horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know here how to display vertical result to horizontal?

Current query result:

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | ALTERNATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 489 | TJ CLASSIC PE 1KG 630 234 | 635 |
| 489 | TJ CLASSIC PE 1KG 630 234 | 859 |
| 490 | CAKE FLOUR 250G | 251 |
| 490 | CAKE FLOUR 250G | 278 |
| 490 | CAKE FLOUR 250G | 703 |
| 490 | CAKE FLOUR 250G | 925 |

Expected result

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | ALTERNATE | ALTERNATE1 | ALTERNATE2 | ALTERNATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 489 | TJ CLASSIC PE 1KG 630 234 | 635 | 859 |  |  |
| 490 | CAKE FLOUR 250G | 251 | 278 | 703 | 925 |

Vertical result for each item, some has more than 20+ result.

Comment: Hint: [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The SQL langauge has a very strict requirement to know the number and meta data for columns in the result set at query compile time, _before looking at any data_. So if you can know for sure there will always be no more than three alternates, this may be possible using the `PIVOT` keyword. Even this, this work is typically best done in client code or in your reporting tool.

Comment: If you can't know how many alternates you need, you're down to dynamic SQL over multiple steps: `1)` Run a query to find out how many alternates you need. `2)` Use results from step 1 to construct a new SQL string to handle exactly that many options. `3)` Execute the SQL command constructed in step 2.

Comment: dale and joel thank you, but is there anyway to do this task without knowing the exact count of altenates ?.  because the table updated everyday and new item will somehow  populate more alternate than yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here along with pivoting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY ALTERNATE) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ITEM,
    DESCRIPTION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ALTERNATE END) AS ALTERNATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ALTERNATE END) AS ALTERNATE1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ALTERNATE END) AS ALTERNATE2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ALTERNATE END) AS ALTERNATE3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ITEM,
    DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: hi tim this is good and working , but as of now, I really dont know the exact count of alternate , because the max count of alternate can change, it depends of the table refresh everyday. is there anyway to do the dynamic value of alternate.